# Git says I delete one line in .pbxproj file when I add new files to my project

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I added two new files to my Xcode project and when I ran git diff on pbxproj file it showed the added files but also indicated that I deleted one line of pbxproj which I didn’t. I have tried discarded all changes and re-add the new files, and it still showed I delete a line in pbxproj. However, I can still build the project without error. What might be the cause?

[image: deleted line]

Comment: I'm not sure that you deleted I line.  I propose that actual the line ending of that line has been changed from `CRLF` to just `LF`, or vice-versa, and Git is therefore making you think that you changed the entire line.

Comment: But all I did is adding new files, I even discarded all changes to make sure I didn’t accidentally delete something.

Comment: Your IDE, Xcode, is messing with things without you knowing it.  If you clean everything with Xcode closed, I'll bet it will work.  But the longer term fix is to deal with your line endings issue.  You're on Mac OS, so the line endings should be `LF`, I think.

Comment: Could you show the "deleted" line?

Comment: @Losiowaty Please see the attached image, just a regular .m file.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Still confused, thank you though,

Comment: I've never used Xcode, but I can tell that IntelliJ definitely can do things to your line endings without you knowing about it.  Well, you find out when you go to use Git afterwards.

Comment: For future - the ids on the left won’t reveal anything about your project, and I applaud your descriptive file naming that you thought it prudent to blur them out :) Anyhow - you have „(null)” in your sources - this means that your project file has indeed some issues, and you should look through it and remove this ghost references. Does the „removed” filename appear anywhere as an added one?